# "Go to declaration" feature on custom MVC helper extension Controllers and Actions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, resharper, extension-methods

In Visual Studio default MVC helpers allow me to jump to the selected Controller or Action:

[image]

But when I create a custom helper extension I'm not able to do this anymore:

[image]

Is there a way to add this feature in Visual Studio/Resharper/or extension method itself?

**UPD:** 
Extension method's code

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MenuLink(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string linkText, string actionName, string controllerName)
    {
        return htmlHelper.ActionLink(linkText, actionName, controllerName);
    }
}
```

Comment: what code do you have in the extension method `MenuLink`? Can you provide code which you are using to redirect in this extension method?

Comment: @johni, I don't see how it's relevant, but I updated the question.

Comment: I am sorry, I believe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resharper allows annotations to guide its magic. They are usually implemented by applying an attribute, though it uses external annotation files for BCL classes. You can use them in your own code. I think they are very underused.

There is an [example](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2011/12/providing-intellisense-navigation-and-more-for-custom-helpers-in-aspnet-mvc/) of exactly your use case. Simply, apply `[AspMvcAction]` and `[AspMvcController]` to the appropriate parameters.

Comment: No but it simply results in attributes on your extension method parameters. If there is some code that enumerates attributes on those parameters (very unlikely), you'll need an assembly that defines them. I believe Resharper is flexible when it matches annotations attributes. It does it by name and not by full identity. So, if you don't want to use their assembly, you can define the attributes in your own assembly.